# Flask-Python redirection to https The connection was reset

Tags: python, redirect, ssl, flask

I am a new Flask user and i have a problem. I want to redirect all url from http to https but I am having this error:

> The connection was reset

This is my Flask code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from flask import *
from OpenSSL import SSL
import psycopg2
import os
from datetime import timedelta
import sys
from flask_sslify import SSLify
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
db_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=billjobs host=192.168.42.96 port=50434 user=username password=password")

app = Flask(__name__)
db = db_conn.cursor()
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=900)
sslify = SSLify(app)
app.secret_key='\xatYK\x1ba\x1dz\xa6-D\x9d\x97\x83\xfa\xcf\xcbd\xfa\xfb\x1a|\x08\x1af'
context = ('ssl.crt','ssl.key')
@app.route('/')
def pre_log():
    return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(host="192.168.42.186", ssl_context=context, debug=False)
```

If I enter directly the address ***https***://192.168.42.186:5000 it work but with ***http*** only its not

Thanks for helping me in advance

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this using `ssl_context` and `Werkzung` (default server of Flask) now. A functionality to allow this was proposed and rejected in 2014: [auto http to https redirect](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/509); citing:

> That requires running another HTTP server. Werkzeug is not capable of that and IMO it's out of scope. run_simple should only be used for development anyway.

So what's going on is your Flask application calls `run_simple` underneath, passing `ssl_context` and some other variables. SSLify has no impact on your routing as long as you use `ssl_context`, because sole presence of this variable makes Werkzung host only using *https* schema. To get redirection from http to https, you need either to set up another server, listening at http and redirecting to https or migrate to other, more advanced server which allows redirection easily.

I recommend to migrate to Apache or gunicorn. Flask provides comprehensive instructions on deployment: [Deployment Options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/). Keep in mind that built-in server of Flask (Werkzung) is not suitable for production, as authors of Flask write:

> While lightweight and easy to use, Flask’s built-in server is not
>   suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well and by default serves
>   only one request at a time.

Using Apache you could redirect all http requests using VirtualHost rule, listening at 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure
</VirtualHost>
```

See more on this on [Redirect Request to SSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) Apache wiki.